# After login the screen should split in to two parts

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an image and want to split it into two parts with button right now its work with click on image while i want to work only with button.

What I had done till now demo is here

[my jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0d1yyq9e/)

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function() 
{  
    jQuery('.center').click(function()
    {  
        var clicks = 0;//var clicks = jQuery(this).data('clicks');
        var width = jQuery(this).outerWidth() / 2;  
        if (clicks == 0) 
        {
            jQuery(this).find('.left_move').animate({ right : width },{queue:false,duration:600});
            jQuery(this).find('.right_move').animate({ left : width },{queue:false,duration:600});
            jQuery(this).css({"height": "auto", "overflow":"visible" });
            jQuery(this).find('.images_holder').css({"cursor": "auto" });
            jQuery(this).find('a').css({"position": "relative","z-index": "102" });
        }
        else
        {  
            //stopt the animation
        }
        ++clicks;
    });  
});
```

Comment: How could you check it if you are sending the information to server, and then you got a response? You need to use ajax.

Comment: Then ask somebody to make it for you...

Comment: You need to have a minimal understanding of what you are doing. Hire a developer or start learning if you do not know. Have you read what kind of questions are allowd on this site?

Comment: thanks for your suggestion i know what kind of question are allowed here. if you cant give answer just ignore it. i just want to split the screen in two after clicking on submit button. and i am developer myself. but not good in Ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {  
    jQuery('#sub').click(function(){
        move();
    });
    function move(){
                jQuery('.center').click(function(){  
var clicks = 0;//var clicks = jQuery(this).data('clicks');
            var width = jQuery(this).outerWidth() / 2;  

              if (clicks == 0) {

            jQuery(this).find('.left_move').animate({ right : width },{queue:false,duration:600});
            jQuery(this).find('.right_move').animate({ left : width },{queue:false,duration:600});
             jQuery(this).css({"height": "auto", "overflow":"visible" });
             jQuery(this).find('.images_holder').css({"cursor": "auto" });
             jQuery(this).find('a').css({"position": "relative","z-index": "102" });


        }
        else{  


        }
++clicks;
        });  
}

});
```

Comment: Thank you very much! can you give me an idea i want to implement it on log In from of WordPress any way thank you once again......